# How to enable a custom stripe payment form in wordpress?

Tags: e-commerce

I want to build a custom payment form using stripe payment method. I go through this https://stripe.com/docs/elements. But I got the following error:
ReferenceError: stripeTokenHandler is not defined

Kindly provide me the proper way to create a custom form using form or solution of error.

Thanks

Comment: This is a _very_ broad request. Please be more specific, show us your research efforts and your code.

Comment: Thanks. But the issue is resolved now.

Comment: @fuxia bUt now I have another issue. I want to remove the address field from billing information from wp payment gateway collect details page.